# Nativescript angular detect first run

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to detect first application run (on new build)? I can think of some custom solutions like a config file where I would write some flag after first run, but this wouldn't help me much. I'd like to show loading screen on first run, which would be different from the runs after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your imports:

`import * as appSettings from "application-settings";`

Then use:

`appSettings.getBoolean("isFirst", true);` - checks if its the first time loading up. If it is, `"isFirst"` won't exist and will therefore return true as `, true)` sets the return to true if the value isn't there.

You can then use:

`appSettings.setBoolean("isFirst", false);` - use this after logging in to set the value of `"isFirst"` for the next time